# Can I Configure SQL Server 2012 Replication on Windows 10 Ultimate?

Tags: sql-server, windows, merge-replication

I have windows 10 Ultimate, I need to install SQL Server 2012 Full Edition and configure SQL Server Replication on it, is that possible or must work on Windows Server?

Answer (score 1):

Replication will work with Windows 10

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to be confirmed before proceeding.
Did you try or see it yourself?

Comment: Yes I have. 2 instances with transnational replication between the 2, which means implicitly I have also seen snapshot, as this is used to initialize transnational. What makes you think that it wouldn't work?

Comment: I assume you are not trying to use web sync, as you have not mentioned it. If you were, this would require IIS obviously (doesn't need to be on same box though)

Comment: I thought that SQL Replication must be configured on Windows Server only (License issue).
My client has 3 branches and I will use SQL Merge Replication to sync between them.

Thanks a lot @Pete,

Comment: This is not a licensing issue. SQL Server Standard Edition supports merge replication and merge replication is supported on Windows 10

Comment: Thanks Peter,
I actually installed SQL Server 2012 Standard on Windows 10 Pro and configured SQL Merge Replication on it.. all are working successfully.